# Remove the focus from whatever has it

Tags: gwt, drag-and-drop, focus

I am handling `MouseDownEvent` and `MouseUpEvent` on an `Image`, in order to allow selection of part of the image.  Most browsers will start dragging the image around unless `preventDefault()` is called on the event, as is visible on this image:

[image]

The major downside of calling `preventDefault()` is that if the focus was on, say, a `TextBox`, it will remain there, even though the click on the `Image` should have removed it.

I couldn't find a way to remove the focus from whatever widget currently happens to have it, or to give the focus to the `Image`.  My only workaround so far is to create a useless `TextBox` that is not visible, and when I want to remove the focus I make it visible, give it the focus, and make it invisible again.  Yuck.  Any better suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make the image focusable you have to add the attribute `tabindex` to the element, then you can call the `Element.focus()` method to put the focus on the image when the user clicks on it.

```
final Image i = new Image("http:...");
i.getElement().setAttribute("tabindex", "0");    
i.addMouseDownHandler(new MouseDownHandler() {
  public void onMouseDown(MouseDownEvent event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    i.getElement().focus();
  }
});
```

Another way if you dont need the image focusable, is just handling the `dragStart` event and prevent the default here instead of in the mouse down and up handlers.

```
i.addDragStartHandler(new DragStartHandler() {
  public void onDragStart(DragStartEvent event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I used "-1" as a tabindex, it still makes the element focusable but it doesn't cycle through it with the tab key.  https://github.com/tsuna/opentsdb/commit/6c1dda8b27a94f00f516ebd4218e85133ff929c8